# unable to chage type: ClusterIP to type: LoadBalancer for kube-dns in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns

When I run `kubectl get svc -n kube-system` it tells me:

```
NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)        AGE
kube-dns   ClusterIP   xx.xx.xx.xx   <none>       53/UDP,53/TCP   13h
```

But when I try to `kubectl edit svc/kube-dns -n kube-system`:

> error: services "kube-dns" is invalid
>
> A copy of your changes has been stored to "/tmp/kubectl-edit-4p5gn.yaml"
>
> error: Edit cancelled, no valid changes were saved.

I am unable to change it to a LoadBalancer...any ideas?

I also tried to create a new kube-dns also but I am unable to get an external-ip; it stays stuck in pending state.

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kubedns-bkp
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 53
    protocol: UDP
  selector:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
```

`kubectl get svc -n kube-system` reports:

```
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kubedns-bkp     LoadBalancer   xx.xx.xx.xx     <pending>     53:32115/UDP    5h
```

Note: I have created k8s cluster with ELB integration, for other services I successfully get external IPs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, two things here:

1. As they advised you in the yaml validation errors that you chose not to share with us, one cannot change the `type:` of an existing `Service`; you have to create a new one, or delete the existing one and recreate it.
2. However, I would strongly, strongly, *strongly* advise against deleting the `kube-dns` `Service` -- you are more than welcome to create a new `Service` of `type: LoadBalancer` and point it at the same `selector:` as `kube-dns` is using. That way anyone who wishes to use the load balanced service can, but the things in the cluster who depend on `kube-dns` being a `ClusterIP` with (likely) that existing xx.xx.xx.xx value can continue as before.

Comment: Hi Matthew, Thank you for response...
I too tried to create a new  service but external ip is not getting its in pending state.
FYI: i have created a k8s cluster with ELB integration (AWS).

kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dns-ilb
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-dns
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 53
    protocol: UDP
  selector:
    k8s-app: kube-dns

Comment: That sounds like a new question, but the short version is to check the apiserver and/or controller-manager logs to see if they are encountering an error while provisioning the ELB. I would guess it's the master Nodes not having the right IAM role, if I were guessing, but TBH there are almost infinite things that can go wrong with AWS and ELBs

Comment: Hi, found a reason for not creating loadbalacer in above scenario.  currently AWS ELB not supporting UDP protocol, only supporting TCP. Is there any way to create loadblancer with UDP.

Comment: Ah, in that case I think you're out of luck with the existing AWS products; you'll have to use your own Ingress controller running haproxy or nginx, in that case

Comment: Can you please suggest any haproxy containers for kubernetes.